# Converting numbers back to Date object in R

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I am reading an `Excel` file using the function `readxl::read_excel()`, but it appears that date are not getting read properly.

In the original file, one such date is `2020-JUL-13`, but it is getting read as `44025`.

Is there any way to get back the original date variable as in the original file?

Any pointer is very appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `openxlsx` package to convert number to date like

```
library(openxlsx)

convertToDate("44025")
```

Or to convert the whole column you can use

```
convertToDate(df$date)
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you could try to use:

```
as.Date(44025)
```

However, you will notice error saying `Error in as.Date.numeric(44025) : 'origin' must be supplied`. And that means that all you need is to know origin, i.e. starting date from which to start counting. When you check, mentioned by Bappa Das, help page for `convertToDate` function, you will see that it is just a wrapper for `as.Date()` function and that the default argument for `origin` parameter is `"1900-01-01"`.

Next, you can check, why is this, by looking for date systems in Excel and here is a page for this:

[Date systems in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487)

Where is an information that for Windows (for Mac there are some exceptions) starting date is indeed `"1900-01-01"`.

And now, finally, if you want to use base R, you can do:

```
as.Date(44025, origin = "1900-01-01")
```

This is vectorized function, so you can pass whole column as well.